# in regex choose lines that begin with edit and ignore remaining characters to insert " at end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

below is part of the text file (whole file is 3600 lines) and I want to add a quote at the end of each line that begins with edit ignoring what comes after until the last character of that individual line to insert the ending " .  I am using regex in notepad++ and find and replace.

```
set subnet 3.0.21.30/32
next 
edit "3.0.34.106/32
set subnet 3.0.34.106/32
next
edit "3.1.217.15/32
set subnet 3.1.217.15/32
next
edit "3.80.211.237/32
set subnet 3.80.211.237/32
next
edit "3.81.91.109/32
set subnet 3.81.91.109/32
```

Comment: Please update the question with the problem you can't solve - add examples you tried, resources you've read and what is not working. Follow these guidelines in general: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**Would something like this be helpful to you?**

**Pattern:**

```
(^edit.*)
```

**Replacement:**

```
\1"
```

https://regex101.com/r/SlSplf/1

**That'll add a quotation at the end. Don't know the limitations of notepad++ off-hand, but from what I'm reading it looks like it'll work for you.**

**Test String:**

```
set subnet 3.0.21.30/32
next 
edit "3.0.34.106/32
set subnet 3.0.34.106/32
next
edit "3.1.217.15/32
set subnet 3.1.217.15/32
next
edit "3.80.211.237/32
set subnet 3.80.211.237/32
next
edit "3.81.91.109/32
set subnet 3.81.91.109/32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented a solution in R - it may not be the most elegant but it got the job done. Maybe you could consider using R instead of notepad but it should have some similar functionality. I used the `str_replace_all` function in package `stringr` to select the last character which is on a line which begins with `edit` and then replaced that character with its value plus a close quote.

Here's how I went about it. First I turned it into a string

```
    string <- "set subnet 3.0.21.30/32
    next
    edit '3.0.34.106/32
    set subnet 3.0.34.106/32
    next
    edit '3.1.217.15/32
    set subnet 3.1.217.15/32
    next
    edit '3.80.211.237/32
    set subnet 3.80.211.237/32
    next
    edit '3.81.91.109/32
    set subnet 3.81.91.109/32"
```

I prefer using double quotes to enclose strings, so I changed all the quotes inside the string to a single quote. Now I add the close quote to the "edit" lines.

```
    library(stringr)
    str_replace_all(string, "(?<=\\nedit(.){0,10000})(.)(?=\\n)", "\\2'")
```

Let's break this down. The syntax for `str_replace_all` is `(string, "expression to replace", "replacement expression")`

We want the expression to replace to be a character at the end of a line which begins with edit. To isolate that character I used a lookbehind and a lookahead. The lookbehind specifies that we want the character to be preceded by a line break, the word "edit", and some number of characters. The second `(.)` is the character we want to replace. I allowed it to be any non-line break character but if it's always going to be a digit as in your example you can change `(.)` to `(\\d)`. The lookahead specifies that we want the character to precede a line break (i.e. to be the last character in its line). Note that the characters in the lookahead and lookbehind aren't included in the selection. This allows us to isolate our character of interest.

The expression we want to replace that character with is `\\2'` The `\\2` refers to the second capturing group meaning the  character(s) enclosed in the second set of parentheses which in this case is the second instance of `(.)` which is the character we're replacing. We replace that with the character itself followed by a close quote.

We can use writeLines to see how the string looks after applying the replacement:

```
    writeLines(str_replace_all(string, "(?<=\\nedit(.){0,10000})(.)(?=\\n)","\\2'"))

  set subnet 3.0.21.30/32
  next
  edit '3.0.34.106/32'
  set subnet 3.0.34.106/32
  next
  edit '3.1.217.15/32'
  set subnet 3.1.217.15/32
  next
  edit '3.80.211.237/32'
  set subnet 3.80.211.237/32
  next
  edit '3.81.91.109/32'
  set subnet 3.81.91.109/32
```

Now all of the "edit" lines have a close quote at the end.

One part of my solution that can perhaps be improved is my use of {0,10000} as a substitute for an infinite number of characters following the word "edit." Lookbehinds don't allow the use of unbounded maximum character strings such as `.*` which is what I originally tried to use in place of `.{0,10000}`. This doesn't seem to matter for your data, but perhaps a more experienced regexer can chime in with a solution for this point.